# RecyclerView doesn't appear in a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Why doesn't RecyclerView appear in my fragment? I've added recyclerview adapter in the fragment, but it still didn't appear. Here are the codes:

FollowersFragment.kt

```
class FollowersFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFollowersBinding
 
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "FollowersFragment"
        const val ARG_NAME = "userName"
    }
 
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_followers, container, false)
    }
 
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentFollowersBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 
        val username = arguments?.getString(ARG_NAME)
 
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        binding.rvFollowers.layoutManager = layoutManager
        val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(requireActivity(), layoutManager.orientation)
        binding.rvFollowers.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
 
        val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getFollowers(username.toString(),"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")
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<List<FollowsResponseItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<FollowsResponseItem>>,
                response: Response<List<FollowsResponseItem>>
            ) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    if(responseBody!=null){
                        Log.d(TAG,responseBody.toString())
                        setUserData(responseBody)
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG,"onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                    }
                }
            }
 
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<FollowsResponseItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }
 
    fun setUserData(item: List<FollowsResponseItem>){
        val listUser = ArrayList<UserResponse>()
        val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        executor.execute {
            try {
                for (i in 0..item.size-1) {
                    if(item.size>5 && i>5){
                        break
                    }
                    val client = ApiConfig.getApiService()
                        .getUser(item.get(i).login, "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")
                    client.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<UserResponse>,
                            response: Response<UserResponse>
                        ) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                val responseBody = response.body()
                                if (responseBody != null) {
                                    listUser.add(responseBody)
                                    if(i==4 || item.get(i).login.equals(item.get(item.size-1).login)){
                                        Log.d(TAG,"user : $listUser")
                                        val adapter = ListUserAdapter(listUser)
                                        binding.rvFollowers.adapter = adapter
                                        Log.d(TAG,adapter.toString())
                                        adapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object: ListUserAdapter.OnItemClickCallback{
                                            override fun onItemClicked(data: UserParcelable) {
                                                showSelectedUser(data)
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${response.message()}")
                                }
                            }
                        }
 
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message}")
                        }
                    })
                }
            } catch(e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
 
    private fun showSelectedUser(data: UserParcelable) {
 
    }
}
```

DetailActivity.kt

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private  lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding
    private var getUserName: String ="sidiqpermana"
    companion object{
        const val EXTRA_DATA = "extra_data"
        @StringRes
        private  val TAB_TITLES = intArrayOf(
            R.string.tab_text_1,
            R.string.tab_text_2
        )
 
    }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
 
        val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<UserParcelable>(EXTRA_DATA) as UserParcelable
        val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this)
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = binding.viewPager
        viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
        val tabs: TabLayout = binding.tabs
        sectionsPagerAdapter.userName = data.login
 
        TabLayoutMediator(tabs,viewPager){ tab, position ->
            tab.text = resources.getString(TAB_TITLES[position])
        }.attach()
 
        getUserName = data.login
 
        showInfo(data)
 
 
    }
 
    fun getUserName() : String{
        return getUserName
    }
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun showInfo(data: UserParcelable){
        Glide.with(this@DetailActivity)
            .load(data.avatar_url)
            .into(binding.detailPp)
        if(data.name.equals("null")) binding.detailName.setText("No Name") else binding.detailName.setText(data.name)
        binding.detailUsername.setText(data.login)
        if(data.bio.equals("null")) binding.detailBio.setText("No Name") else binding.detailBio.setText(data.bio)
        binding.detailFollowers.setText("${data.followers} Followers")
        binding.detailFollowings.setText("${data.following} Following")
        if(data.location.equals("null")) binding.detailLocation.setText("No Location") else binding.detailLocation.setText(data.location)
    }
}
```

ListUserAdapter.kt (RecyclerView Adapter)

```
class ListUserAdapter (private val listUser: ArrayList<UserResponse>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListUserAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback
 
    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback){
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }
 
class ListViewHolder(var binding: ItemUsersRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
 
    }
 
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemUsersRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context),viewGroup,false)
        return ListViewHolder(binding)
    }
 
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var (followers,avatar_url,following, name,bio, location, login) = listUser[position]
        name = name ?: "No Name"
        bio = bio ?: "No Bio"
        location = location?: "No Location"
        holder.apply {
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(avatar_url)
                .into(binding.photoProfile)
            binding.profileName.setText(name.toString())
            binding.username.setText(login)
            binding.followers.setText("$following Followers")
            binding.followings.setText("$following Followings")
            binding.location.setText(location.toString())
 
            val detailUser = UserParcelable(followers,avatar_url,following,
                name.toString(), bio.toString(), location.toString(), login)
            itemView.setOnClickListener{ onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(detailUser)}
        }
 
    }
 
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listUser.size
    }
 
    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: UserParcelable)
    }
}
```

Help me solve this problem please.

Comment: This is too much code to go through . Try debugging the Issue step by step. See exactly what happening .. First make sure adapter is getting the data or not .

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to initialize adapter every time you want to update the list. Either make your `ListUserAdapter` extend `ListAdapter` and than use `adapter.submitList(listUser)` or if you want to extend `RecyclerView.Adapter` as you do, you can do the following :

```
class ListUserAdapter () : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListUserAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {

  private val listUser: List<UserResponse>

  fun submitList(newList: List<UserResponse>) {
     listUser = newList
     notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val listItem = listUser[position]
    ...
  }


  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listUser.size
  }
}
```

I suggest you go with `ListAdapter`. Check if `Log.d(TAG,"user : $listUser")` is printed, if it is and `listUser` is not empty than call `adapter.submitList(listUser)` and RV should be populated.

Comment: Seconded, go with ListAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to notify adapter about the changes, So after
**binding.rvFollowers.adapter = adapter** call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**

Comment: There is not need of `notifyDataSetChanged` just after setting the adapter .. you only call `notifyDataSetChanged` if you change the data set .